# Neural Net Setup

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm trying to implement a single hidden layer neural net for MNIST digit recognition in Python.

Like the following:

```
               h1             
x1                            z1
               h2
x2                            z2
 1             h3

                1
```

I'm using a hidden layer of size 200.

The number of features for the digits is 784.

The number of classes is 10.

Each label is transformed to a vector of length 10 which has a single 1 in the position of the true class and 0 elsewhere.

Between the input and the hidden layer, I'm going to use a 200 by 785 matrix V.

Matrix V: the i, j - entry represents the weight connecting the jth unit in the input layer to the ith unit in the hidden layer. The ith row of V represents the ensemble of weights feeding into the ith hidden unit.

Between the hidden the the output layer, I'm going to apply a matrix W, which is 10 by 201.

Matrix W: the i, j - entry represents the weight connecting the jth unit in the hidden layer to the ith unit in the output layer. The ith row of W is the emsemble of weights feeding into the ith output unit.

**So I start with the input matrix, which is n by 784. Can someone explain what to do? What do I need to multiply it by, and then what/how do I multiply the result by? I'm not sure how exactly to multiply these matrices.**

(Let's just call the activation functions f().)

I'm a bit confused by the dimensions of the matrices and not sure when /where/ how exactly to use V and W.

Comment: [This](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/) is a nice and comprehensive introduction to neural networks and on the way they implement a neural network to classify the MNIST dataset in python.

Comment: I will break this down for you, but you need to read a lot more about NNs to understand how it works (don't forget, programming is 90% studying/planning and 10% coding). So, input dimension is n x 785 and hidden dim is n x 200. The weights (w) are defined as: w=transpose(input_dims) * hidden_dims. You should use transpose to bring your data in the proper fit for matrix multiplication: w=785 x n * n x 200. This will give you a w of size 785x200 which is the desired output. (the * here means matrix multiplication).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic simulation step of a feed-forward neuronal network (Ported from my cpp neuronal network [here](https://gist.github.com/tobspr/b2646085835fc244b8f9a0a38c90ab83#file-neuronalnetwork-cpp-L29)):

```
def simulate(inputs):
    currentActivatedValues = inputs
    for i in range(len(self.weights)):
        summedValues = _weights[i] * currentActivatedValues + _biases[i]
        # Perform activation function with the summed values
        for k in range(len(summedValues)):
            summedValues[k] = tanh( summedValues[k] );
        currentActivatedValues = summedValues
    return currentActivatedValues;
```

The issue is basically that you were including the bias in your initial matrix. What you should do is processing them afterwards.

Have a look at this [paper](https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs294a/sparseAutoencoder.pdf) about feed forward neuronal networks. It includes all the formulas you need to setup a basic one.